# What do you call this stacked folders looking view in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, view, ios7, directory

[image: Pls see this link]
<sub>(source: [mshcdn.com](http://rack.3.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEzLzA5LzE5Lzc4L3BlcmZlY3R3ZWF0LjUzOGVhLnBuZwpwCXRodW1iCTg1MHg1OTA-CmUJanBn/f3bec24a/e27/perfect-weather-2.jpg))</sub>

What is this view called?

Its like stacked folders (Cupertino, New York, Austin, Your Location) that when you touch one.

It enlarges and shows more details, is it complicated to create?

And can someone please show me a link, on how to create one?

Thanks.

Comment: Insert the picture. I am not trusting your external links, nor can anyone else be forced to do so.

Comment: I think I saw this on passbook if im not mistaken?

Comment: Can be created using UIKit Dynamics and I believe those are just UIViews on top of each other and positioned accordingly. There is a tutorial the iOS7 By tutorials book that creates an app with the same function and look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a lot like an [Accordion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_%28GUI%29).

There are a number of Accordion projects on [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=accordion) and [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=accordion).

Answer (score 1):

This is just using a `UITableView` and customising what happens when you tap cells.

You don't need `UIKit Dynamics` for something like this. Nor would I put multiple `UIViews` on top of each other as if there are more than a handful you'll run into memory issues.

The transition to the next screen is a custom transition. You can read more about these in WWDC 2013 video. I think it's session 218.

Or possibly in the tech talk videos available from the http://developer.apple.com website.

The iOS weather app uses a similar concept. I'm about 30% through trying to reverse engineer it. I believe it uses a `UICollectionView` with a layout-to-layout transition.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard view controller layout. I think you could call this "Stacked View Controllers", as it is not per se a navigation controller (no push/pop), nor a tab bar controller, nor anything known.